# Batch PostgreSQL para ejecutar archivo .sql

Tags: postgresql

Estimada comunidad un gusto saludarlos, debo crear un batch que me permita ejecutar comandos internos de PostgreSQL para eso tengo este batch.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET BACKUPS_DIR=c:\temp\
SET SQLEXE_DIR=c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\PGPASSWORD="mypasswd"
SET USER=postgres
SET PORT=5432
SET PASSWORD=mypasswd
SET DATABASE=mydb
SET SERVER=localhost

psql -h %SERVER% -p %PORT% -U %USER% -d %DATABASE% -f 'myqry.sql'

pause
```

El problema que tengo es que siempre me pide contraseña no consigo hacer que ejecute directamente el archivo .sql sin que pida la contraseña, estoy usando Window10 64bits postgresql 14.

Agradezco su gentil atencion.

Comment: pero tienes que colocarle para autenticar, sería algo como: `psql --host %SERVER% --port %PORT% --username %USER% --pasword %PASSWORD% --database %DATABASE% -f 'myqry-sql'`

Comment: Hola lsanchezo, lo probe pero me indica "psql: illegal option -- pasword" saludos.

Comment: password, con doble s. lo coloqué mal

Comment: Hola lsanchezo, me sale: 'psql: precaución: se ignoró argumento extra «--database» en línea de órdenes
psql: precaución: se ignoró argumento extra «pruebas» en línea de órdenes
psql: precaución: se ignoró argumento extra «-f» en línea de órdenes
psql: precaución: se ignoró argumento extra «'consultit.sql'» en línea de órdenes
Contraseña:'

Comment: amigo este foro es para preguntas no para que te hagamos los deberes